# Where should I place the application logic of non-web, non-batch Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to start my non-web/non-batch Spring boot application properly.

However, if I place the main tasks in a `CommandLineRunner` it also gets triggered while running the tests. Running the tasks as batch job will work, but my task doesn't follow batch job semantics.

Is extending `SpringApplication` class and putting the logic in `run()` method after `super()` call the standard way?

Comment: No. The "standard" way would be to place your business logic in a Service class and call this from the runner.

Comment: You can make sure that the `CommandLineRunner` is only being created for certain profiles. So if you do that, and make sure you don't use those profiles while executing tests, I don't think there's any problem?

Comment: The command line runner that calls my service also gets invoke when I run unit tests.

Comment: Thanks @g00glen00b . That works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you annotate your `CommandLineRunner` bean with the `@Profile` annotation, you can tell Spring to only create the bean when running with (or without) certain profiles, for example:

```
@Component
@Profile("autorun")
public class JobRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    // ...
}
```

As long as you don't use those profile when testing, it should not be invoked. You can then run the application using the `-Dspring.profiles.active=autorun` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate Component class and assign a profile

```
@Component
@Profile("!test")
public class RunApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws IOException {
        //Your code here 
    }
}
```

This class will only be initialized when the `spring.profiles.active` variable is not equal to test

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html